# Set background text

Tags: image, text, background, widget, pyqt

Does anyone know how I can set background text for a QListWidget?

I've previously used

```
self.setStyleSheet("background-image:myBgImg.png")
```

but I want to create the text within the app. i.e:

```
bgImage = QImage()
bgImage = bgImage.setText( "textKey" , "This is some background text." )
palette = QPalette()
palette.setBrush(self.listWidget.backgroundRole(), QBrush( bgImage ))
self.listWidget.setPalette(palette)
```

though this doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem you have is that you are overrideing bgImage with None, if you look at the [setText method](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qimage.html#setText) you will see that it returns void, since you are passing None to the QBrush there is nothing to draw. Try with:

```
bgImage = QImage()
bgImage = bgImage.setText( "textKey" , "This is some background text." )
palette = QPalette()
palette.setBrush(self.listWidget.backgroundRole(), QBrush( bgImage ))
self.listWidget.setPalette(palette)
```

An other approach that does work is to extend the list and implement the paint event:

```
import sys 
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class MyList(QtGui.QListWidget):
    """A funny list."""

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        """Paint the widget."""
        # paint the widget
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.viewport())
        # paint here
        super(MyList, self).paintEvent(event)
```

You have to make sure that you use the viewport to paint and not self since you will get QPainter::begin: Widget painting can only begin as a result of a paintEvent.